# How i can delay the action, to bot will ignore second command until i do first command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
client.on('message', async (message) => {
    let author = message.author.username
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.content.startsWith('-queue open ')) {
    message.content = message.content.replace('-queue open ', '')
    message.channel.send(`Queue has been created with number of members: ${message.content}`).then(m => setTimeout(() => {
        m.delete()
    }, 2000))
}
});

client.on('message', async (message) => {
    let author = message.author.username
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.content === '-queue') {
        message.channel.send("You've been added to queue!").then(client.channels.cache.get('818898462111301663').send(`Member [${author}] has queued`))
    }
})
```

I wanna to if member didn't write command **-queue open**, bot will ignore command **-queue** until i write it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are new to DiscordJS.

```
client.on('message', async (message) => { EXECUTABLE CODE HERE });
```

This code is an event. It triggers every time a message is received. If it's triggered the executable code within the event is triggered and executed.

You should **not** listen to this event twice. This means you can not have two `client.on('message')` code blocks in your code.

If you want to listen for a reply (after the event has been triggered), you should look into [message collectors](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html).

*For more information on DiscordJS events:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/WSEventType
https://gist.github.com/koad/316b265a91d933fd1b62dddfcc3ff584*

Comment: To clarify, you *can* listen to this event twice, you just *shouldn't*